# Angularjs Binding Dropdown using ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I have looked at the angular documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions but still can't figure this one out.

I have a list of sexes that get bound to a select like this:

```
            $scope.sexes = jQuery.grep(formData, function(a) {
                return (a.category == "Sex");
            });
```

the JSON for the sex list looks like this:

```
            2: Object
            alternateCode: null
            category: "Sex"
            code1: "F"
            codeID: 60002
            description: "Female"
            lastModifiedBy: ""
            lastModifiedDate: "1900-01-01T00:00:00"
            subCategory: null
```

The member object that should make the select choice has a property on it **sex:M**.  The problem is when I try to bind the select it will populate the list correctly but will not select the option I need:

```
            <select name="sex" id="sex" class="form-control"
                    ng-model="editableMember.sex"
                    ng-options="s.sex as s.description for s in sexes track by s.code1 "></select>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: _it will populate the list correctly but will not select the option I need_ do you mean you cannot select the option in the dropdown, or the model doesn't change when you select the option, or the option you expected to be the default selection isn't selected?

Comment: appologies I mean the value on my member object passed in which has a property sex:m does not select the value M in the option when the page loads

Comment: The values need to be identical, so a property value of "m" on the object will not select the "M" option. Could this be what you're experiencing?

Comment: no the JSON comes back like this ,"sex":"M"

Comment: Then I suspect it's not being set to `editableMember` correctly. Check the model value by adding `<span>Sex: {{ editableMember.sex }}</span>` before the select. Does it have the value "M"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you missed this part of the documentation:

> Do not use select as and track by in the same expression. They are not designed to work together.

The `ng-model` value will be the result of either the `select` or `track by` expression. The following code for `ng-options` should work:

```
ng-options="s.code1 as s.description for s in sexes"
```